# PHP Bypass jQuery Codes

Tags: php, javascript

I use this codes to save my contacts information into MySQL Database and apply JQuery Confirm Function for confirmation of data submitting, but when confirmation dialog open PHP Scripts can't stop, or Php bypass JQuery confirm codes and submit data into database, any idea regarding this issue.

```
<?php
//Database connection.
include'connect.php';
if(isset($_POST['name'])&&isset($_POST['email'])&&isset($_POST['contact'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];

if(empty($name)&&empty($email)&&empty($contact)){
echo'
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("Please fill all fields.");
    });
  </script>
';
 }else{
  if($sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO contact_list VALUES ('', '".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($contact)."')")){
    echo'
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
           confirm("Are you sure to Saved Contact?");
        });
      </script>
    ';
  }else{
    echo'
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            alert("Something is wrong, Please check");
        });
      </script>
        ';
     }
 }
 }
 ?>

<html>
   <form action="#" method="POST">
      Full name:<input type="text" name="name">
      Email:<input type="text" name="email">
      Contact:<input type="text" name="contact">
   </form>
</html>
```

Comment: PHP is server-side, jQuery is client-side. You save data on server and then echo script to client. Nothing bypasses anything.

Comment: Boss any idea to handle this issue

Comment: See answer of @TheBronx, that will help.

Answer (score 3):

PHP is executed by the server while javascript is executed by the client. And you want the server to "wait" or "stop execution" until some js code is executed by the client. Well, it's not possible.

You have to split your PHP code in two different PHP scripts: one for confirmation and one for data saving. For example, with pseudocode:

**confirm.php**

```
Hey, are you sure you want to save the data?
<a href="save.php">Yes, I'm sure</a>
```

**save.php**

```
INSERT INTO 'blablabla' VALUES bla bla bla bla bla
```

Of course you don't really have to split it into two scripts. You can add one more $_POST parameter like "confirmed=true/false" and instead of two scripts just have one with one more `if () {} else {}` block.

But the idea is that you have to separate the two actions, cause you can't do both the confirmation and the saving at once with PHP.

---

There are also a few more options:

1. Use ajax to run the "saving script" once user confirms the operation
2. Use javascript to prevent the "saving script" from running without confirmation, something like: `<input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Sure?');" value="Save"/>`